# Azure media server rest example

Tags: rest, azure, azure-media-services

I am trying to find a sample project which utilizes rest / json to upload videos and manage them to azure media service.

I am not able to use the .net wrapper which is available via nuget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into some code snippets for utilizing REST/JSON to upload videos:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj129593.aspx. You can check out most of REST APIs documentations here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh973629.aspx.

Comment: I have begun to write a portable class library which utilizes the rest api instead - seems the only way